# Textarea does not autogrow height with pre-filled value after append from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on Spring Application. I want to set the pre-filled value into textarea and show it to the user. I need that textarea to show multiple lines where the height according to the content.

I tried some scripts from the internet but no luck.

I created the sample code in order to understand my goal.

```js
function submit() {
  $("#text").remove();
  let data = `<textarea id="text" rows="1">asdaaaaaaa
  asddas
  asasd
  assd
  daasd
  dsasd
  sdasd
  asdasd</textarea>`
  $("#banner-message").append(data);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <div><button type="button" onclick="submit()">Click Me!</button></div>
</div>
```

I want the `textarea` autogrow height to fit the content after appending from the jquery.

Comment: can't you simply add `rows='8'` instead of `rows='1'` ? Or the value will always be dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this, I set timer to reload the content using javascript.

The reason why the content loaded by javascript did not work because the html has not loaded yet, so by using timer to reload the content from javascript after the html loaded, it will work just fine. You can try to reduce the duration to low as you want and test it if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Calvin Nunes's comment, you may try something like this (after appending the node).

```js
function submit() {
  $("#text").remove();
  let data = `<textarea id="text" rows="1">asdaaaaaaa
  asddas
  asasd
  assd
  daasd
  dsasd
  sdasd
  asdasd</textarea>`
  $("#banner-message").append(data);
  // count number of lines in text's value
  var numRows = ($("#text").val().match(/\n/g) || []).length + 1;
  $("#text").attr("rows", numRows);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <div><button type="button" onclick="submit()">Click Me!</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, eventually, the rows attribute did not seem to change the height of element textarea. Did I miss something

Comment: @laughing updated the solution with snippet, you may try to run the snippet and test

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to create a textarea dynamically which is better and it gets easier with jquery. Check for the line breaks and assign that much rows to the text area.

```js
function submit() {
  $("#text").remove();
  let data = `asdaaaaaaa
  asddas
  asasd
  assd
  daasd
  dsasd
  sdasd
  asdasd`
  let textarea = $(document.createElement("textarea")), // new element of textarea
    matches = data.match(/\n/g), // match the line breaks from data
    breaks = matches ? matches.length : 2; // get the length or return 2
  textarea.val(data) // append the value to the textarea
  textarea.attr('rows', breaks + 2); // assign the attribute to the texarea
  textarea.attr('id', "text"); // assign the id to textarea
  $("#banner-message").append(textarea); // append the textare to the div
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <div><button type="button" onclick="submit()">Click Me!</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any other option? because I append lots of elements within the loop, along with style class and dynamic id.

Comment: That’s the best option within a loop. You should use react.js for this